# Git: Move a folder from one branch to another in Node.js

Tags: node.js, git, npm, branch, git-branch

I have a folder in my `master` branch (which is listed in the `.gitignore` file) called `exports/docs/`. I want to move the contents of the folder into a new branch called `docs`. The folder will not exist in the master branch (because of the *.gitignore*) but should exist in the `docs` branch.

## File structure

### branch `master`

```
project
|--- .gitignore
|--- /exports
     |--- /docs
          |--- file1.txt
          |--- file2.txt
```

#### .gitignore

```
exports
```

---

### branch `docs`

```
project
|--- file1.txt
|--- file2.txt
```

How do I do this in a **Node.js** script? and is there any **npm** package to help me do so?

**Thanks**

Answer (score 0):

Refer https://gist.github.com/wizioo/c89847c7894ede628071 to create a script post git checkout abd create branch specific .gitignore files. And then u can have the file in both the branches locally but while pushing it, the push will behave differently according to its ".gitignore".